# How to increase Username Limit

Tags: members, username

Can anyone recommend the file I need to hack in order to increase the username limit?  I believe it is 25 characters and I need it increased.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not at my workstation, so I can't search for you, but here is a technique I've used for tracking down code specifics inside a code base. SSH in to an EE app server and navigate to `system/expressionengine`. If you can figure out a specific expression that is related to limiting user name length (such as `count($username) >`) you can use `grep` to search through text/PHP files for instances of that expression:

```
grep -nr . -e "count($username) >"
```

You probably have to escape the expression because it is a regex search. But that command should recursively search and return what file and line number the expression is found in.